# json net deserialize dynamic attribute in version 4.5

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to deserialize a json string and there are many dynamic attributes with prefix in common,I wanna collect these dynamic attributes into my collections,here is my situation,I have the type：

```
public class TestType
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="property1")]
    public String Property1;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="property2")]
    public String Property2;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="dyamicproperties")]
    public List<String> DyamicProperty  
}
```

and also I get the json content:

```
{
    "dynamic_property1": "sample 3",
    "dynamic_property2": "sample 4",
     //there maybe many other keys starts with 'dynamic_xxxxxx',maybe not
    "property1": "sample 1",
    "property2": "sample 2"
}
```

the result should looks like

```
...
var result = JsonConvert.Deserialize<TestType>(jsoncontent)
...
result.DynamicProperty //////["dynamic_property1,dynamic_property2"]
```

how to?
**notes:** I use json.net 4.5 so I can't use JsonExtensionDataAttribute which in version6.0.0

Comment: Write a `JsonConverter`. There's no magic that will do your job.

Comment: Thanks! I use JsonConverter and done